# Solution to inhomogeneous PDE by method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, characteristics

I am trying to solve the system
$$\begin{cases}
u_t+\omega\cdot\nabla_x u=f(t,x) \\
u(0,x)=u_0(x)\\
\end{cases}$$
for some $\omega\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I have the system of ODEs
$$\frac{dt}{ds}=1$$
$$\frac{dx_i}{ds}=\omega_i$$
$$\frac{du}{ds}=f(t,x)$$
Thus, using the initial conditions, I obtain $t=s$, $x=x_0+\omega s=x_0+\omega t$, and $u(t,x)=sf(t,x)+u_0(x_0)$. Thus, my solution is $u(t,x)=tf(t,x)+u_0(x-\omega t)$. This appears to satisfy the condition $u(0,x)=u_0(x)$. Is my solution correct?

Comment: You can check via differentiation that it doesn't satisfy the equation. First, the characteristics for $x$ only hold if $\omega$ is constant, else it should be $$x_{i} = x_{i, 0} + \int \omega_{i} ds$$ Second, integrating $$\frac{du}{ds} = f(t(s), x(s))$$ does not yield $$u = s f(t(s), x(s)) + u_{0}(x_{0})$$ due to the functional dependence of $f$ on $s$.

Comment: @MatthewCassell I should clarify, here $\omega$ is a constant in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I see what you mean about the dependence of $f$ on $s$. In that case, would it simply be $$u(t,x)=\int_0^t f(s,x-\omega t+\omega s)ds+u_0(x-\omega t)?$$

Comment: I think you mean $\omega$ is a constant _vector_ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. And yes, the result you posted in the comment for $u$ looks more like the answer, though differentiation still shows the integral term to be incorrect. It should just be $$u(x, t) = u_{0}(x - \omega t) + \int_{0}^{t} f(s, x) ds$$

Comment: @MatthewCassell Anon's expression is correct. You've forgotten to apply the $\omega\cdot\nabla u$ term in the differential operator to the integral over $f$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog You are absolutely right, I did forget. I shouldn't do maths late at night. To Anon, my apologies, your result in the comments is correct and mine was most definitely wrong.

Comment: @MatthewCassell Thanks for catching my mistake and pointing me in the right direction! Much appreciated.